# laravel how to update the selected value from selection immediately

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, selection

I am working on a laravel project, I wanna create a selection that the selected value updated immediately when I click the selection, here is the markup:

```
   <select name="survey_option", id="survey_option" class="flex space-x-3 items-center">
                 
          <option value="NoLink" disabled>Please select</option>
          <option value="option 1">option 1</option>
          <option value="option 2">option 2</option>
                 
   </select>
```

here is the script:

```
<script>
survey_option=$('select[name=survey_option]').val();
</script>
```

here is the api:

```
$selected_label = $request->survey_option;
```

current result is that I can make a selection, but the selected value cannot be updated immediately after I click the selection. Can you plese help me to figure it out? Many THX!

Comment: fyi, no commas between attributes and `<div>` is not allowed in `<select>`

Comment: @brombeer thanks for your comments, I just updated my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<div>` tag should not be present within the `<select>`.

```
<select name="survey_option" id="survey_option">
   <option value="NoLink" disabled>Please select</option>
   <option value="option 1">option 1</option>
   <option value="option 2">option 2</option>
</select>
```

To achieve this, you should attach an `change` event listener to the select element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name=survey_option]').on('change', function() {
        var survey_option = $(this).val();
        console.log(survey_option);
        // your codes
    });
});
```

you can check console to make sure that you get correct option value in function

Comment: thanks for your help! i just tried your method, the console.log works well, the selected value updated every I change the selection, but in my api, the received value still doesn't update immediately, I updated my api code, can you please have a look? THANKS!

Comment: @RA.IBOY You'd have to handle that on your own where `// your codes` is. Needs a little more info. What is your API? When does it get called? How are you passing the changed value to your API?

Comment: @brombeer I use the API to receive the request and make some calculation. i put the code in my main question part. can you please have a look? THANKS!

Comment: That "api" alone doesn't help. What code have you placed for `// your codes` that handles updating your api? (That should probably be a question on its own, since this question seems to be solved by this answer) Do you make any AJAX request to update your "api"?

Comment: @brombeer thanks for your help! I will ask another question.